# How do I populate a 2D array with values?

Tags: java

So I'm making an airline reservation program and I'm trying to populate a 2D array with seat numbers and changes per airline company, this is what I have so far

```
public class BoeingSeatMap extends SeatMap{
protected int row;
protected char column;
SeatType seatType;
Seat s1;

public void intializeSeatMap(){
    this.row = 10;
    this.column =  7;
    char [][] seats = new char[row][column];
    for(int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++){
        for(int y = 0; y < seats[i].length; y++){
        //  seats[i][y] = s1.reserved(false);

        }
    }
}

}
```

This airline company has 10 rows and 7 columns, the first 4 rows are also first class and the layout is 2-3-2 (window, aisle, aisle, middle, aisle, aisle, window)

I want to have the array populated with 1A, 1B etcetc.

Comment: So, what's not working with that code?

Comment: @resueman I dont know how to populate it with 1A etc. aswell as setting the reservation boolean to false

Comment: Well a `char` can only store a single character. There's not way to make it contain that much data. Pick a data type that represents the data you want to store.

Comment: I think you are confused and think you can label your seats like this `seats[1][A]` as you might be thinking that since this is a 2d char array that would mean that you can refer to the seat that way, which you cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `Seat[][]` instead of a `char[][]`, which can hold all the data you want.

Here is a basic example:

```
class Seat {
    
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;
    private boolean reserved = false;

    public Seat(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // ...Getters & Setters...

    public enum Type {
        Business,
        Economy;
    }
}

class BoeingSeatMap {
    private Seat[][] seats;
    
    public static final int rows = 10;
    public static final int columns = 7;
    
    private static final String[] letters = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };

    public void intializeSeatMap() {
        seats = new Seat[rows][columns];
        
        for (int x = 0; x < seats.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < seats[x].length; y++) {
                String name = (x + 1) + letters[y];
                if(x < 4) { // first 4 rows are Business
                    seats[x][y] = new Seat(name, Seat.Type.Business);
                } else { // The rest Economy
                    seats[x][y] = new Seat(name, Seat.Type.Economy);
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Example output:

```
[1A : Business, 1B : Business, 1C : Business, 1D : Business, 1E : Business, 1F : Business, 1G : Business]
[2A : Business, 2B : Business, 2C : Business, 2D : Business, 2E : Business, 2F : Business, 2G : Business]
[3A : Business, 3B : Business, 3C : Business, 3D : Business, 3E : Business, 3F : Business, 3G : Business]
[4A : Business, 4B : Business, 4C : Business, 4D : Business, 4E : Business, 4F : Business, 4G : Business]
[5A : Economy, 5B : Economy, 5C : Economy, 5D : Economy, 5E : Economy, 5F : Economy, 5G : Economy]
[6A : Economy, 6B : Economy, 6C : Economy, 6D : Economy, 6E : Economy, 6F : Economy, 6G : Economy]
[7A : Economy, 7B : Economy, 7C : Economy, 7D : Economy, 7E : Economy, 7F : Economy, 7G : Economy]
[8A : Economy, 8B : Economy, 8C : Economy, 8D : Economy, 8E : Economy, 8F : Economy, 8G : Economy]
[9A : Economy, 9B : Economy, 9C : Economy, 9D : Economy, 9E : Economy, 9F : Economy, 9G : Economy]
[10A : Economy, 10B : Economy, 10C : Economy, 10D : Economy, 10E : Economy, 10F : Economy, 10G : Economy]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a char array to store such data since it can only store a single character ('a','b','c' etc). As mentioned above from resueman you have to choose another data type that can store much more information like String etc.

Or even better try making your own custom object since you have already SeatType and Seat.